# How to convert a string into Hex in TypeScript and back to String in Python

Tags: python, typescript, hex

I have a use-case where a TypeScript application should print a string in hex and a Python application should read this hex and convert it back to string.

The TypeScript code I have:

```js
function stringToHex(str: string): string {
  return str.split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).join('');
}
```

The Python code I have:

```py
def hexToString(hex_str: str) -> str:
  return bytes.fromhex(hex_str).decode('utf-8')
```

I'm trying to run this:

```js
hexEncode("def main():\n  print(\"Hello World\")\n\nif __name__ == '__main__':\n  main()")
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I have control on both sides. Where am I going wrong on this?

Comment: Ditto, I've tried both your TypeScript and Python code.  "hello" encodes to "68656c6c6f" and that decodes in Python to "hello".  You didn't mention how you got the output of one to the input of the other, but perhaps it got mangled.

Comment: @MichaelM. For example: `console.log(hexEncode("def main():\n  print(\"Hello World\")\n\nif __name__ == '__main__':\n  main()"))`. I believe it's because of `\n` because `hello` works but `hello\n` does not work.

Comment: @vesii Ah, you just aren't encoding new line characters correctly because `.toString(16)` doesn't add leading zeroes. See my answer below.

Comment: @vesii Have you been able to resolve this issue? If so, then did my answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're not correctly padding the output of `char.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)`. Two hexadecimal digits represent one byte, therefore you need to add leading zeros to the result of the `.toString(16)` if the output is only one character long.

Take for example a new line character (`\n`). Its char code is `10`, which is `a` in hex, so you'll need to pad it with a leading zero. If you don't do this, Python doesn't know that that single `a` is supposed to represent a single byte and all the data is shifted.

To fix this, just call `.padStart(2, '0')` after `.toString(16)`. Try changing your TypeScript function to this:

```
function stringToHex(str: string): string {
  return str.split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
}
```